# Unable to test growlyflash notifications.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Using this gem https://github.com/estum/growlyflash I am attempting to write test cases for it using capybara and rspec.

I know that its an XHR, and that capybara usually waits for the page to load( or check again after a short period).

The notifications work, but I am not able to test them. Not really sure what to do.

Test case looks like this.

`expect(page).to have_content("A message has been sent!")`

Comment: Why can't you test them? What results do you get? I assume you're using a JS capable driver with Capybara?

Comment: Yea. So the error says 

Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("A message has been sent!")
       expected to find text "A message has been sent!")" in "Sign out Send a Message Show All Messages

Comment: It seems that the notification tab disappears before capaybara gets that far? or maybe its all JS.

Comment: As long as the notification tab is visible for long enough for a human to read it, capybara should see it too -  I would guess you have other errors in your test case, post the whole test case so there is some context around the error - Also what driver are you using in capybara?